# Different values in different editors

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, libreoffice, translation

I opened same document with `OpenOffice` and with use of `Microsoft Word`. Document language is english and I use operating system also with english language. `MS Word` opens the document correctly, but `Open Office` and also `Libre Office` translate some word to hungarian without any user interaction. Editing is disabled in each cases, but replace happens automatically.

Comment: could you post some screenshots? What are those part? in a field, or just plain text?

Comment: @MátéJuhász These are words in table cells.